# SQL Server - Cannot truncate table involved with an indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have to modify a data warehouse. A complex ETL is modifying that data warehouse.

I added an indexed view over a handful of tables to make things easy and fast. The code looked like this:

```
CREATE VIEW
  my_current_view WITH schemabinding
AS
SELECT ...
FROM table1 ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx1 ON my_current_view (tranid)
```

And now the ETL fails with the following message:

> Executing the query "truncate table table1 " failed with the following
>   error: "Cannot TRUNCATE TABLE 'table1 ' because it is being referenced
>   by object 'my_current_view '."

I figured out I need to remove (not to add) the unique index so truncate table will happen:

```
CREATE VIEW
  my_current_view WITH schemabinding
AS
SELECT ...
FROM table1 ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY ...
```

Is there a way to have this other object (table, view, whatever) in sync with the underlying tables **and** have indexes?

Comment: Sure -- omit the `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. The drawback of this is that the view will yield incorrect data if the physical column order changes, or if you do something silly like `SELECT *`. These are relatively uncommon cases, but they can cause a lot of headaches if you do run into them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, note that one cannot create an index on the view without `WITH SCHEMABINDING`.

Comment: Doy. Managed to completely miss the "and have indexes" bit, which, you know, is easy because it was written in bold and all... I'll go wear the brown paper bag now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be bad news but indexed views must use schema binding and that does not permit truncate table. You'll have to drop the indexed view, truncate the table, then put it back.

Comment: Minor correction: it's not the fact that the view is `SCHEMABOUND` that prevents it from being truncated, that is actually allowed. Once it's materialized into an indexed view is when you can no longer truncate, that is specifically a limitation against index views.

Comment: Note: Whilst you can't truncate a table, you can delete from it.  Not ideal, but you can delete in batches to minimise its impact on logs (e.g. as is done with the [Remove-DbaDbTableData](https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/blob/master/public/Remove-DbaDbTableData.ps1#LL177C24-L177C24) cmdlet from the `dbatools` module

Comment: Yep, you can just delete a few thousand at a time in a loop, if you're comfortable with the performance hit. For a big table, you still might be better removing the view, truncating it, and putting it back, as long as it's not being used in the meantime. It's a pity there isn't an option to disable an indexed view, and then later repopulate it. That would at least keep the metadata the same way it does for disabling indexes.